# Gatsby JS: integrating cubeportfolio gallery and redrawing after onRouteUpdate

Tags: react-router, gatsby, image-gallery

I had an old php site using a theme I bought, which uses the **cubeportfolio 4.1** image gallery... see plugin: [here](http://scriptpie.com/cubeportfolio/live-preview/) and [here](https://codecanyon.net/item/cube-portfolio-responsive-jquery-grid-plugin/6372959).

I am rebuilding the site as a static site with gatsby, and have had to rebuild the gallery component by:

- moving all the static assets (css, js etc) into my `/static` gatsby folder
- hardwiring all the necessary js and css links as into my `html.jsx` file
- fetching my image assets from graphql and rebuilding the gallery with very basic react components

Amazingly it works, and the *cubeportfolio* image gallery populates and resizes all the images into a perfect grid. Mouseovers etc also work.

## problem:

when I navigate away, and come back to the home page (i.e. change routes), the *cubeportfolio* grid doesn't redraw itself! The image assets are just dumped on the page and nothing kicks in to shuffle them into a grid of appropriately resized elements. So, all i know at this point is that ***there is a bit of javascript somewhere that should be re-triggered, but isn't***.

Googling, I found a snippet and tried adding the following to `gatsby-browser.js`:

```
exports.onRouteUpdate = () => {
   // force cubeportfolio to redraw
   $(window).trigger('resize.cbp');
}
```

This did not work. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

OK figured it out. I found the code the old theme was using to set up cubeportfolio. It was in one of the static js files, so I think it was loaded once at startup and then subsequent returns to the page with the gallery didn't necessarily reload the js file.

Fix was to lift that code and move it to `gatsby-browser.js`:

```js
exports.onRouteUpdate = ({location}) => {
   // force cubeportfolio to redraw
   if (location.pathname === '/') { // or path to whatever page has cubeportfolio
     $('#grid-container').cubeportfolio({...}); // pass needed options
   }
}
```